# Writing to a selected or activated excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to add some vlaue or text from a simple Userform to an existing Excel-File. After opening the Excel-File the user should be able to choose a sheet and then write add the textbox.text to the selected sheet. I am using a combobox to select or acitivate the sheets.See the code below:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (comboBox1.Text)
        {
            case "Sheetname":
                //((Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1]).Select();
                xlWorkBook.Sheets[1].Activate();
                break;
            case "Scheetname":
                //((Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[2]).Select();
                xlWorkBook.Sheets[2].Activate();
                break;
        }
```

However after choosing the right Sheet, my Program keeps writing the values to the first sheet.

The code that I use for adding to the Excel-Sheet is the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Hier werden die daten eingetragen!
        {
                int lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 1] = textBox1.Text;
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 2] = textBox2.Text;
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 3] = textBox2.Text;
          }
```

For opening the Excel-File I use this code:

```
xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

xlexcel.Visible = true; //Tabelle ist Sichtbar

// Datei öffnen
xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("mypath");

xlWorkSheet =(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[comboBox1.SelectedText];
```

Is anyone able to help me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing in `xlWorkSheet` the initial value selected in the combobox when you first open the workbook. It does not matter what you are doing afterwards or which worksheet is active, the variable always refers to the first one they chose. You need to update the variable when they choose a new value in the combobox:

```
void OpenExcel()
{
    xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

    xlexcel.Visible = true; //Tabelle ist Sichtbar

    // Datei öffnen
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("mypath");

    // store first selected sheet in variable
    xlWorkSheet =(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[comboBox1.SelectedText];
}


private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // select new sheet and update variable to refer to it
    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "Sheetname":
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.Sheets[1]);
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            break;
        case "Scheetname":
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.Sheets[2]);
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            break;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Hier werden die daten eingetragen!
{
    int lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 1] = textBox1.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 2] = textBox2.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[lastRow, 3] = textBox2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works now !! And Sorry for my bad spelling and thank you for editing my question. I did not reread my questions!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Activate()` method to `Select()` Method.
[How to: Programmatically Select Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x62t5306.aspx)

> The Select method selects the specified object, which moves the user's
>   selection to the new object. Use the Activate method if you want to
>   bring focus to the object without changing the user's selection.

Comment: First of all thank you for your fast answer. I replaced the method as you said. The Problem is I think, when I am opening the file. This Line I think is the problem: xlWorkSheet =(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[comboBox1.SelectedText];